# Android GCM: Why it sometimes fails?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Have been experiencing this in my app, sometimes the GCM registration occured fast, sometimes it takes like 1hr+ to register it.

I've tried researching it but I didn't find any explanation. Based from my research other people also experienced this. Does anyone know why?

Comment: My guess is simply connection problems phone -> google -> phone?

Comment: Well it could happen, but with a internet connection that is not slow.. But still, I'm curious if there is a explanation other than that..

Comment: Does anything happen in your logs? How do you know it's taking a hour? In all of my tests it's happened very quickly, usually less than 2 seconds.

Comment: Well, usually that is the case, but sometime the gcm just keep trying registering due to ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. From the codes of gcm, the retry time will increase due to this lines in GCMBaseIntentService.java from the gcm library:
int backoffTimeMs = GCMRegistrar.getBackoff(context);
int nextAttempt = backoffTimeMs / 2 +sRandom.nextInt(backoffTimeMs);